# Send input value to Url.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input id="toPay" type="text" readonly>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Home", new {price = toPay.Value})">
        <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to send the `toPay` value as a parameter to the `Create` action method that is of type `HttpGet`. How can I do something like this `new {price = toPay.Value}`

Comment: I didn't quite get what do you need. You may be confusing a few things. Forms are used for Post requests and links for Get request, which one do you need?

Comment: @PedroSouki The submit button should acts like a link.

Comment: To use a button to act as a link and use a HttpGet method, intercept the submit event with javascript and use jquery to make the Get request. But to Create you should use the Post request. That why I said that there is some confusion in your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" >
   @Html.Textbox("toPay")
   <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The input element needs to be inside the same form

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Home")">
<div>
    <input id="toPay" type="text" readonly>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>

</div>
</form>
```

The data will then get passed across in the http body as a POST message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div> 
<form>
   <input id="toPay" type="text" readonly/> //close input tag
</form>
</div>
<div>
<form>
 <input type="button" value="Pay" id = "pay"/> // make this change
</form>
</div>
<script>
    $('#pay').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Action("Create", "Home") + '?price =' + $('#toPay').val()
            type: 'POST',
            // ... other ajax options ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

and with the helpers it's more easier :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Textbox("toPay")
    <input type="submit" value="Pay" />
}
```